# Mapping a virtual property without created a computed column in Entity Framework Core 6.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am using .Net 6.0 with .Net Framework Core 6.0.

In database, I have a table with 3 columns.

- UserId: int
- FirstName: varchar(100)
- LastName: varchar(100).

In C# Entity, I have a User Entity with 4 properties.

- UserId : int (Map to UserId column)
- FirstName: string (Map to FirstName column)
- LastName: string (Map to LastName column).
- FullName: string (It's a SQL calculated column, by [FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName].

To do this, I configure in OnModelCreating something looks like this.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(c => c.FullName).HasComputedColumnSql("[FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName]", false);
```

In consuming code, I call DbSet.ToList();

- What I expected EF will generate a query "`select UserId, FirstName, LastName, (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) FullName From User`"
- But actually, EF generated this query "`select UserId, FirstName, LastName, FullName From User`", and it throws an exception "`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Invalid column name 'FullName'`".
  '

I don't want to create an extra computed column on the User table, just want to have a virtual column in generated SQL.

I don't want to calculate the FullName property on C# memory, by complex business use case, it needs to be coming from SQL calculated.

Can you please help me to resolve this?
.

Comment: As an FYI, `(FirstName + ' ' + LastName) FullName` isn't a calculated/computed column. A computed column is defined as part of the table, not in the `SELECT`.

Comment: @Larnu Hi Larnu, yes. I understand the root cause. But my purpose is to be able to get the FullName from SQL calculated. Do we have any solution to work around?

Comment: Use `Select`, you can compose any entity in such case.

Comment: `FullName` should be a computed *property* in the entity. Why should the database compute it, and make it a redundant part of the payload in the SQL result, if the entity has all information it needs?

Comment: @GertArnold, the FullName property is just a simple sample that I can describe here. Actually, the calculated property has a very complex business, which is calculated from multiple DB columns, and I use the calculated property for DB sorting and paging. That's why It needs calculate from DB.

Comment: Either add your computed column to the database table or make it a computed property in the entity as stated by Gert Arnold. The error message is telling you that you're treating it like a computed column in the database table, but it is not present in the database.

Comment: Then I think only you can decide what's better. We can't help you based on this bit of information.

Comment: To me, this seems like a bug. The current doc of ef core (7) clearly state that you can do it either way ( HasComputedColumnSql with store = true/false).

Comment: @Michael `store = true/false` means that on SQL Server side column is persisted or not. I.e. it either materialized and stored on disk or is a virtual column calculated every time. But it still should be declared/present on the server side.

Comment: I actually managed to make this work by extending / overriding some core methods in EF.
Basically, I added
`public static PropertyBuilder<T> HasCustomExpressionSql<T>(this PropertyBuilder<T> builder, 
    string selectSql, string insertOrAddSql, string? insertSql = null)`
which can be used like this:
`builder.
    Property(e => e.SpecalValue)
    .HasMaxLength(50)
    .HasColumnName("SPECIALCOLUMN")
    .HasCustomExpressionSql(
        "someSelectStoredProd([COLUMN_A], [COL_B])",
        "someInsertStoredProd([COLUMN_A], [COL_B], [COL_C])"
        );`